# Switch Color For an SVG Asset On Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

I am trying to add a svg asset file for my app. But I dont know if my code is working is fine or not because `SvgPicture.asset` has no color property. I´m posting the code below:

```dart
 Row(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 20.w,
                        height: 10.h,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.h),
                          color: Colors.pink,
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 1.h,
                              bottom: 1.h,
                            ),
                            child: SvgPicture.asset(
                              'assets/icons/tablet.svg',
                              height: 7.h,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 20.w,
                        height: 4.h,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Text('İlaç'),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

It looks like this:

> (https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLj1T.png)

NOTE: There is no error on log

It should look like this:

> (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DPmz.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
class ArrowForwardIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  
  const ArrowForwardIcon({super.key,});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const color = Colors.red;
    return SvgPicture.asset(
      'assets/arrow-forward.svg',
      colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(color, BlendMode.srcIn),
    );
  }
}
```

replace color with desired Color in the example.

Essentially, this just filters the color of the source svg to the selected color using the colorfilter object provided. you could get very unique color filtering by changing the blendmode. but I'm sure you just only want to change the color of your svg.

Comment: i couldnt add to child. can you write full code?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg   just placed the code in the current documentation of flutter_svg in a stateless widget. Update to the latest version